# trim string at the end of the string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I want to remove the last word from my sentence in C#. Here is my query:

```
"SELECT * FROM People WHERE City = @City AND County = @County AND"
```

I want to remove the last AND programatically, how can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM People WHERE City = @City AND County = @County AND";
var scrubbed = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
string myString = "SELECT * FROM People WHERE City = @City AND County = @County AND";
Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(0, myString.LastIndexOf(' ')));
```

But you may also consider building your AND-clause without the last AND from the beginning.

```
List<string> andConditions = new List<string>();
andConditions.Add("City = @City");
andConditions.Add("County = @County");
string myString = "SELECT * FROM People WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", andConditions);
```

Comment: +1, What an ingenious way of "_removing_" the last 'AND' ... I always added it within the loop (`myString += condition + " AND ";`) and then added a Trim outside of my loop to remove the fat, but this is far nicer! :)

Comment: @myermian, If you may have 0 conditions you can also add the `" WHERE "` in an `if (addConditions.Count > 0) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

If the final word is always going to be "AND":

```
if (yourString.EndsWith(" AND"))
    yourString = yourString.Remove(yourString.Length - 4);
```

Or, if you need to truncate everything beyond the final space:

```
int index = yourString.LastIndexOf(' ');
if (index > -1)
    yourString = yourString.Remove(index);
```

(Although, [as Donnie says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226657/trim-string-at-the-end-of-the-string/4226704#4226704), the real correct answer is to not append the superfluous final word to your string in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple methods for fixing the string given already.

This looks like dynamically generated SQL, so, the more sensible solution in my mind is to never have the final `AND` there.  This can be done by counting the number of parameters you've added to the `where` clause, and *prepending* the `and` for every parameter after the first.

Answer (score 0):

also, can be done via

```
//............
string query = SELECT * FROM People WHERE City = @City AND County = @County AND";
char[] charsAND = { 'A', 'N', 'D'};
char[] charsOR = { 'O', 'R'};
query = query.Trim().TrimEnd(charsAND).TrimEnd(charsOR);
//
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a double quote.

Comment: This does a different job. Your answer can be made workable like `query.TrimEnd('D').TrimEnd('N').TrimEnd('A')`;

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
string myString = "SELECT * FROM People WHERE City = @City AND County = @County AND";
myString = myString.TrimEnd(" AND".ToCharArray());
```