# How to remove a suffix from end of string?

Tags: c#, string, .net-3.5

I want to:

1. Check a variable and determine if the last 2 characters are "Id"
2. If yes, remove them.

I can do it with this below, but then it will blow up if there is an "Id" substring other than the end.  Is there a RemoveFromEnd() method that takes a number of characters argument?

```
 if (column.EndsWith("Id"))
 {
       //remove last 2 characters
       column = column.replace("Id", "");
 }
```

I see [this solution](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-string-end), which does this:

```
column = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(column, "Id$", "");
```

but it says it's pretty slow and I am going to be running this code inside a code block that I would like to be extremely fast so I wanted to see if a faster solution is available.

Comment: Just curious how "slow" the regexp is (an end-anchor w/o backtracking should be zippy-fast) ... although substring is likely more appropriate here. OTOH, with the regexp there is no explicit conditional/EndsWith.

Comment: The Regex should be faster in the general case. Did you try with precompiling it or storing it as a member to use it in your method? (to avoid the cost of creating the regex each time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [trim string at the end of the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226657/trim-string-at-the-end-of-the-string)

Comment: The snippet you put removes all "Id" from the string if it has it as suffix, it will return "MyWrong" if the input string is "MyIdWrongId"...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`String.Substring` can do that:

```
column = column.Substring(0, column.Length - 2);
```

You can use it to roll your own `RemoveFromEnd`:

```
public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string s, string suffix)
{
    if (s.EndsWith(suffix))
    {
        return s.Substring(0, s.Length - suffix.Length);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this approach if you don't want to use a regular expression. But really, how could this be faster?

Comment: @DOK: faster than what? the regexp?

Comment: @DOK: the string manipulation methods in .NET are highly performant. For simple operations like this I often find them to be very much faster than regular expressions.

Comment: Considering the startup cost of a regex? I'd be pretty surprised if regex were faster for this.

Comment: can be modified to one-liner return s.EndsWith(suffix) ? s.Substring(0, s.Length - suffix.Length) : s;

Comment: Need a `TrimEnd(this string, string, string)` et. al. :)

Comment: Could be modified to single line methods using c#6 [expression-bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition) methods and c# 8 [ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-): `public static string RemoveFromEnd(string s, string suffix) => s.EndsWith(suffix) ? s[..^suffix.Length] : s;`

Answer (score 17):

An alternative to the `SubString` method is to use a `Regex.Replace` from `System.Text.RegularExpressions`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
column = Regex.Replace(column, @"Id$", String.Empty);
```

This way enables you to avoid the test, but not sure if it is really a speed benefit :-). At least an alternative that might be useful in some cases where you need to check for more than one thing at a time.

The regex can be compiled and re-used to get some performance increase and used instead of the call to the static method and can be used like this:

```
// stored as a private member
private static Regex _checkId = new Regex(@"Id$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
...
// inside some method
column = _checkId.Replace(column, String.Empty);
```

Comment: Did you ever made a comparison between compiled regex and `EndsWith`-`Substring`?

Answer (score 6):

Well, there can be a `RemoveFromEnd()` method if you write your own:

```
public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string str, string toRemove)
{
    if (str.EndsWith(toRemove))
        return str.Substring(0, str.Length - toRemove.Length);
    else
        return str;
}
```

You can just use it as follows:

```
column = column.RemoveFromEnd("Id");
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you know the length of the part to remove, you can use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx):

```
if (column.EndsWith("Id"))
{    
    column = column.Substring(0, column.Length - 2);
}
```

Comment: If the last two characters are not Id, this will remove them in error.

Comment: @DOK: this is intended to be inside the if block, of course (instead of the call to `Replace` in the OP. Will add if-block for clarity though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (column.IndexOf("Id") == column.Length-2) {
    column = column.Substring(0, column.Length-2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the (relatively) new [Range Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-) introduced in C# 8 you can simplify the `RemoveEnd` method even more:

```cs
public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string s, string suffix)
{
    if (s.EndsWith(suffix))
    {
        return s[..^suffix.Length];
    }

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes to add to @Jon's answer:

Do you want to do this case insensitively?

```
if (column.ToLower().EndsWith("id")) { column = column.Remove(column.Length - 2); }
```

If ID is unique in the string and needs to always be removed...

```
 #No if check....
 column = column.Replace("Id", "");
```

If its case insensitive and only occurs once I would still use the first check.

Comment: -1; this fails the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html). It's probably still fine for most contexts (since most code never needs to run in a Turkish locale), but for some readers, this code will effectively be broken.