# Add strings to a string separated with a comma

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to add strings to a string but separated with a comma. At the end I want to remove the , and space. What is the cleanest way?

```
var message =  $"Error message : ";

if (Parameters != null)
{
    Parameters
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => message += $"{x.Key} - {x.Value}, "); // <- remove the , " at the end
}

return message;
```

Parameters is a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to remove a suffix from end of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284591/8017690)

Comment: No need to remove anything. Don't put it there in the first place. Use `String.Join`.

Comment: `ToList` is useless if `Parameters` already implements `IEnumerable<>` (is a List<>, IList<>, array, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this with `String.Join`

```cs
message += string.Join(",",Parameters.ToList().Select(x => $"{x.Key} - {x.Value}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use join method but if you want to know idea you can see this code

```
var message =  $"Error message : ";
var sep = "";
if (Parameters != null)
{
    Parameters
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => {
            message += $"{sep} {x.Key} - {x.Value}";
            sep = ",";
         });
}

return message;
```