# How to trim the end of a string after the first occurrence of a char C#

Tags: c#

I want to trim the end of a string after the first occurence of a given character, in this case '.'

This character appears multiple times in the string.

- Input: 143.122.124.123
- Output: 143

I can find multiple questions similar to this alhtough they all use `LastIndexOf()`; where as this requires the first occurence and remove the rest of the string.

Comment: Use IndexOf instead of LastIndexOf then? :)

Comment: Many similar topics: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578254/to-get-specific-part-of-a-string-in-c-sharp 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868517/split-string-and-get-first-value-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trim string at the end of the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226657/trim-string-at-the-end-of-the-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To get specific part of a string in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578254/to-get-specific-part-of-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Fabiano Not a duplicate, your suggested duplicate is trimming a known value off the end of a string, OP's question is to trim an unknown string from the end of a string. In 4226657 they always want to trim " AND".

Answer (score 5):

```
input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('.'))
```

Explanation:

1. Use [`String.IndexOf(char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx) to get zero-based index of first char occurrence in string. E.g. for your input it will be the fourth character with index `3`.
2. Use [`String.Substring(startIndex,length)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the substring from the beginning of the string. Use the index of char as the length of the substring, because the index is zero-based.

Note:

pros of this solution (comparing to using `Split`) is that it will not create arrays in memory and will not traverse all string searching for split character and extracting substrings.

cons of this solution is that string must contain at least one character you are looking for (thanks to Ivan Chepikov for mentioning it). Safe alternative will look like

```
int index = input.IndexOf('.');
if (index != -1)
    substring = input.Substring(0, index);
```

---

Actually, there is a lot of options to do what you want:

1. Fast `input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('.'))`
2. Minimalistic `input.Split('.')[0]`
3. For Regex lovers `Regex.Match(input, @"[^\.]*").Value`
4. For LINQ maniacs `new string(input.TakeWhile(ch => ch != '.').ToArray())`
5. Extension methods for clean code lovers. `input.SubstringUpTo('.')`

Comment: It would be good to check that input.IndexOf('.') != -1 just to be sure that input contains the char.

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "143.122.124.123";
string output = input.Split('.')[0];
```

This will return the entire string if the `Split` character isn't found.

Comment: `input.Split(new char[] {'.'}, 2)` is a bit better choice (in case of long strings with many dots)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Actually I think you can pass the count as `1` rather than `2`.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: Sorry but we want `2` items, they are: `143` and `122.124.123`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ah yes of course, you have to pass 2 even if you only want one part, otherwise it won't split it.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: my message is `output = input.Split(new char[] {'.'}, 2)[0];` we split the `input` into an array with at most `2` items - `["143", "122.124.12"]` and then take the 1st one - `"143"`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yep, understood. (I was agreeing with you.)

Answer (score 1):

(I'm posting this just for completeness - Sergey's answer seems to be correct and simplest.)

(1) A Linq approach:

```
s = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => c != '.').ToArray());
```

(2) Same as Sergey's answer, but using a `Left()` string extension:

```
string s = "143.122.124.123";
s = s.Left(s.IndexOf('.'));
```

Should really do error checking though:

```
string s = "143.122.124.123";
int n = s.IndexOf('.');

if (n >= 0)
    s = s.Left(n);
```

---

Note: The `Left()` method is actually an extension method, so really it's just the same as Sergey's answer:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Left(this string self, int count)
    {
        string result = self.Length <= count 
            ? self 
            : self.Substring(0, count);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a link to `Left` method documentation?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Ooops I was accidentally using an extension method; I'll add it!

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. I thought there is some framework update which I missed :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I've been using those string extensions for so many years now, I totally forgot they aren't part of the standard .Net library! Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

And now we got nuts and **insist** on using `.LastIndexOf()`:

```
string input = "143.122.124.123";
string rev = new string(input.Reverse().ToArray());
string output = new string(rev.Substring(rev.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).Reverse().ToArray());
```